# How to assign a random number a string value in my program

Tags: java, if-statement, random

as the title suggests I am doing a program for homework that is a slot machine. I have searched around and I am pretty satisfied that the program works correctly enough for me. The problem Im having is on top of generating the random numbers, I am supposed to assign values for the numbers 1-5 (Cherries, Oranges, Plums, Bells, Melons, Bars). Then I am to display the output instead of the number when my program runs. Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction on how to do this please?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class SlotMachineClass {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Coins = 1000;
    int Wager = 0;




    System.out.println("Steve's Slot Machine");
    System.out.println("You have " + Coins + " coins.");
    System.out.println("Enter your bet and press Enter to play");




    while (Coins > 0)
    {
    int first = new Random().nextInt(5)+1;
    int second = new Random().nextInt(5)+1;
    int third = new Random().nextInt(5)+1;

    Wager = input.nextInt();

    if(Wager > Coins)
             Wager = Coins;

    System.out.println(first + " " + second + " " + third);


    if(first == second && second == third)
    { Coins = Coins + (Wager * 3);
         System.out.println("You won " + (Wager * 3) + "!!!!" + " You now have " + Coins + " coins.");
         System.out.println("Enter another bet or close program to exit");}

    else if((first == second && first != third) || (first != second && first == third) || (first != second && second == third))
    { Coins = Coins + (Wager * 2);
         System.out.println("You won " + (Wager * 2) + "!!!" + " You now have " + Coins + " coins.");
         System.out.println("Enter another bet or close program to exit");}

    else {Coins = Coins - Wager;  
    System.out.println("You Lost!" + "\nPlay Again? if so Enter your bet.");}



    }

    while (Wager == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("You ran out of coins. Thanks for playing."); 
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The first thing I thought of was an array. But the assignment and teacher wont allow them. I believe a switch statement is in order but I just never used one and dont really know how to code such a thing.

Comment: How are you supposed to assign the six possible fruits to the numbers 1-5? Is more than one fruit mapped to the same number?

Comment: sorry about that, its 0-5, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-array solution most likely to be used a by new programmer in an intro course would be a nested if-else:

```
String fruitToPrint = "";
if (num == 0)
   fruitToPrint = "Cherries";
else if (num == 1)
   fruitToPrint = "Oranges";
else if (num == 2)
   fruitToPrint = "Plums";
else if (num == 3)
   fruitToPrint = "Bells";
else if (num == 4)
   fruitToPrint = "Melons";
else if (num == 5)
   fruitToPrint = "Bars";
else
   System.out.println("Couldn't assign fruit from num=" + num);

System.out.println("The corresponding fruit was " + fruitToPrint);
```

Comment: Ok, i see where you are coming from here, how exactly would incorporate that into my program so that all three int's get the name of the fruit?

Comment: @StevenEck  Copy the above code block into your program 3 times, and in each copied block replace `fruitToPrint` with `firstFruit`, `secondFruit`, and `thirdFruit`. This will create 3 `String` instances and correctly assign each one given the random number. Then you can run `System.out.println(firstFruit + " " + secondFruit + " " + thirdFruit);` It would be better practice and more concise to move the `if-else` chain into its own function, but that's probably coming in lesson 2.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have a working slot machine!!!! Too bad it doesnt give out real money. Its guys like you on here that really make me excited to keep going.

Comment: @StevenEck  Just try not to rely on SO too much. A lot of learning in programming comes from banging your head against a problem a dozen different ways until the right solution hits you.

Comment: @StevenEck  BTW on SO there is a little check-mark under the up/down vote tool next to my answer, which is used to "accept" an answer as having addressed your question. Just a hint. ;-)

Comment: Thanks again. I fixed the ticker. I understand what you're saying about relying too much on help. I guess I have to start to get more comfortable in the idea that I can do it myself. Sometimes it seems so overwhelming but I love doing it. I suppose it's practice, practice, practice.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an `int` and want to have some `String` associated with that, there are a couple of ways to do that.

The first one is to have an array of Strings and look them up.

```
public static String[] text = new String[] {"Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Bar", "Seven"};
public String getNameForReel(int reelValue) {
    return text[reelValue];
}
// And to call it...
System.out.println(getNameForReel(first)); //etc...
```

Or, you can do it in a switch statement (I don't prefer this, but you might):

```
public String getNameForReel(int reelValue) {
    switch(reelValue) {
       case 0: return "Cherry";
       case 1: return "Bell";
       case 2: return "Lemon";
       case 3: return "Bar";
       case 4: return "Seven";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that the switch statement will do the trick but being new to java im not sure what the code is "ForReel" or "reelValue" is that something I need in the program or is that substituting something, and if so, what exactly. Thanks :)

Comment: `reelValue` is an integer that you are passing to the method. In your case, it is either the variable `first`, `second`, or `third`. The `getNameForReel` is a *method* which take the `reelValue` you pass it and works on it.

Comment: `reelValue` would be whatever variable for which you're trying to get a string representation: `println(getNameForReel(first) + " "` and so forth.

Comment: Ok, just so I got this straight, I need to make 3 switch statements for the first, second and third, correct? The getNameForReel is my method that I may 'lend' to another class if need be? Sorry for being so slow on this stuff, we just did classes last week.

Comment: No, you only need one method. As others have suggested, you don't really need the method, you can just access the array directly! 
`System.out.println(text[first]);` For example.

Answer (score 2):

You need a lookup table:

```
String[] text = new String[] {"Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Bar", "Seven"};
```

Then you can just do

```
System.out.println(text[first] + " " + text[second] + " " + text[third]);
```

without creating more methods.

Comment: Mine uses no extra methods.

Comment: Much better (and +1). I'll clean up my comments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array:

```
String[] s = {Cherries, Oranges, Plums, Bells, Melons, Bars};
```

Then you can print `s[num-1]` instead of `num` (where num is the random int). E.g. if your random int came out to be 2, print s[2-1] i.e. s[1] which will be Orange.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution to the question which I think follows best programming practices. This is probably even less allowed for your assignment than an array, and will be a dead giveaway that you got your answer on StackOverflow, but the problem would lend itself to using an `enum` type with an `int`->`enum` mapping:

```
enum Fruit {
   Cherries(1), 
   Oranges(2), 
   Plums(3), 
   Melons(4), 
   Bars(5);

   private static final Map<Integer, Fruit> lookupMap = new HashMap<Integer, Fruit>();
   static {
      for (Fruit fruit : Fruit.values()) {
         lookupMap.put(fruit.getLookup());
      }
   }

   static Fruit fromLookup(int lookup) {
      return lookupMap.get(lookup);
   }

   private final int lookup;       

   private Fruit(int lookup) {
      this.lookup = lookup;
   }

   int getLookup() {
      return lookup;
   }
}

void printEnumExample() {
   int fruitToPrint = 4;
   System.out.println(Fruit.fromLookup(fruitToPrint)); // <- This will print "Melons"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I imagine thats next semester stuff :)